# transform and getcomponent not being recognized after importing unity project from another computer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So
I recently moved some projects over to a new computer,
zipped the files, and then opened them in unity.
they all worked fine - as in the game and scripts both worked when opening on the new PC
but when I looked at the scripts mono behavior was not being recognized and there were a few errors showing up - however it still worked fine even with the apparent errors.
also, unity engine was not being used
I check the potential fixes on vs community and clicked the first one (foolishly)
now Getcompnonet and transform are not being recognised by vS community
my game wont run
and i have no idea what i did wrong.
but now i am using unityEngine?

Getting error cs0103

Comment: It might be that you are trying to open your script files individually. They probably need to be opened in VS Code in the context of the entire unity project / solution. If you have a .sln file in the root of the project, try opening that. Or, try regenerating it from the editor preferences: Edit > Preferences > External Tools

Comment: Check that your Visual Studio has the Unity Workload installed, you can find it in Visual Studio Installer -> Modify -> Workloads -> Game Development with Unity

Comment: so it works with other projects that I have newly created 
and I have the unity package installed
so dont think it is that
and I've tried what you said joseph and nothing sadly

i have just seen that yesterday a new script  was created solely with public class monobehaviour {}
that was what made it forget what transform and getcomponent was

Comment: okay apologies guys. I have just deleted the new monobehaviour script and everything sorted itself out.
cheers for the help though guys. I'm pretty new to this so yeah really appreciate that!

Comment: just a final point is that I had the same issue with some other projects that I had moved over from another PC
and that fix works on that too
so I generated mono behaviour in a new file then simply deleted it and it all sorted itself out.  can anyone explain why that happened?